# How to get UK company share certificates when an entrepreneur does not comply?

Tags: united-kingdom, shares, equity, contracts, crowdfunding

In January 2020, I made an investment of £7,500 being promised that I would receive the respective share certificates related to UK company.

After that, the pandemic became the excuse but the entrepreneur assured me that my shares were safe.

Occasionally (like 5-7 times) I exchanged some emails with him. Sometimes he replies when the matter is about the progress of the company but has been avoiding replying when the matter are my shares.

This is a UK company that I had previously invested in through CrowdCube (a crowdfunding website in the UK) which is why I thought there should be no problem.

The agreement was just a simple chat via email and very clear. The amount I invested in, the bank account to send the funds and the valuation at which I invested were stated in writing.

What options do I have to secure my shares?

Comment: Do you have a signed contract?  Have you contacted CrowdCube?

Comment: It might be worth checking companies house for a "conformation change" filing / CS01 and an "annual return" (this is free and public to lookup). It's worth reading about companies' requirements to report [share changes](https://www.gov.uk/make-changes-to-your-limited-company/share-structure).

Answer (score 3):

If the 7,500 investment was made privately and not through the CrowdCube service, then Small Claims Court may be the only answer.